# Form Validators firing on Umbraco

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, umbraco

We are developing a web application in Umbraco 4 and have come across an intermittent problem when posting data between pages. When a form submission is posted to a new page all of the validators are firing causing various unwanted results, we have tried various posting methods using different buttons with the same result.  Has anyone else come across this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation group is working but I got to the bottom of the issue.

One of the submit buttons on the page was a html submit, with no runat server, so the code-behind didn't know where the submit had come from, so all validations where fired, regardless of validation group

Comment: Ahh, nice one. Don't forget to accept your own answer so we know this question is solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

All postbacks events, unless otherwise specified, will cause all validators on a page to be triggered. Either...

A) Set the `ValidationGroup` property on each of the validators as well as the control which you do want to trigger validators to the same name.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valName" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtName" ValidationGroup="AllRequired" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AllRequired" OnClick="..." />
<asp:Button ID="btnSkip" runat="server" OnClick="..." />
```

In this case, `btnSkip` won't trigger the validators.

B) Set the `CausesValidation` property on the control which you don't want to trigger validation to `false`.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="..." />
```